# unchecked generics usage warning on getAllClassMetadata() instance method of org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, generics

I just cant understand this.
I'm calling

```
AnnotationConfiguration annotationConfiguration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = annotationConfiguration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
Map<?, ?> allClassMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
```

Well, the only way I don't have warning is if I'm using wildcard `?` But! if I look at definition of getAllClassMetadata() method in the `SessionFactory` interface or any of it's implementation the returning type is `Map<String,ClassMetadata>`. So, the problem is. When I write

```
Map<String,ClassMetadata> allClassMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
```

Eclipse tells me `The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,ClassMetadata>` I just don't get this. It's dumb. Please help.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: sorry, my fault, I used some old version of hibernate without parametrization and attached sources of the newer version, thus there was difference between what I'm thinking and what is in real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This javadoc link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getAllCollectionMetadata%28%29) says `getAllClassMetadata()` returns a `Map`